# cannot install ember-cli-fastboot on windows7

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to install node module ember-cli-fastboot(v0.5.0) for my project, there is some problem while installing, Can anyone help me resolving the issue

[Sreenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc1Ns.png)

Answer (score 0):

node-gyp on windows require Visual C++ toolkit

- On Windows:

  - Option 1: Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).
  - Option 2: Install tools and configuration manually:

    - Visual C++ Build Environment:
    - Option 1: Install [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) using the **Default Install** option.
    - Option 2: Install [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) (or modify an existing installation) and select *Common Tools for Visual C++* during setup. This also works with the free Community and Express for Desktop editions.

    > [Windows Vista / 7 only] requires [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773)

    - Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (`v3.x.x` is not supported), and run `npm config set python python2.7` (or see below for further instructions on specifying the proper Python version and path.)
    - Launch cmd, `npm config set msvs_version 2015`

  If the above steps didn't work for you, please visit [Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules) for additional tips.

If you have multiple Python versions installed, you can identify which Python
version `node-gyp` uses by setting the '--python' variable:

`bash
$ node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7`

If `node-gyp` is called by way of `npm` *and* you have multiple versions of
Python installed, then you can set `npm`'s 'python' config key to the appropriate
value: